# SID in url shows as SID= and doesn't pass the id with FPC

Tags: magento-enterprise, url, full-page-cache

I have a webstore that links to 5 other webstores and passes the sid param so that we can share cart and what not. The site and this functionality has worked fine for the last 2 years. The website is setup using Enterprise 1.11 and utilizes default FPC

However, we just recently started noticing that when linking to one of the webstores that is mainly a landing page, which links to the other stores, the SID is sometimes blank.

We started noticing when trying to have affiliate links going to that site and then transferring the affiliate source to the other stores through the session.

after thinking about it and wondering how the SID's were changing with FPC on anyways without any page hole, I found that it is handled in this class

```
Enterprise_PageCache_Helper_Url
```

I am only able to reproduce it by going to the site, making sure the page is cached, deleted the frontend cookie through web dev tools, refreshing the page and noticing that it isn't generating a new frontend cookie, thus maybe there is no new session id that can be pulled into to fill in the correct SID on the links.

I would believe that if a page was cached and a user gets there without ever having a frontend cookie it should have that set in FPC processing process. I am thinking this is a bug but maybe I am wrong.

I am wondering if anyone can provide any insight into this. I tested the same thing on a 1.13 instance. If you go to a page, make sure it is cached delete your frontend cookie, refresh the page you will see no new frontend cookie.

Comment: Dan - can you provide an update on this and submit / mark your own answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We've run into issues very similar to this and I think they were core bigs which we ended up getting a patch from enterprise support for. My suggestion is to reach out asking for a patch, especially since you noted you can reproduce in a clean 1.13 instance, it's probably not custom code.

Comment: Thanks @davidalger, I was going to submit support and figured I would post here first to see if anyone else had seen this issue.